# RUBY Programming - Help?

Tags: ruby

I'm following a guide to Ruby programming, which requires me to create a new folder to use as my main programming library.

I ran into the problem where the *Guide requires right-clicking in the folder and select NEW* and from the NEW drop window choose an option to a new Ruby program.

The thing is, after installing Ruby and looking all over the net for answers, I cannot for the life of me figure out why that option does NOT APPEAR in the NEW section when right clicking to create documents etc. Can anyone help me get it to appear in the NEW menu?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't create an empty text file, then rename it to `.rb`? I'm not sure what you'd gain from such an entry in the menu besides that.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which editor or IDE you are using.

Comment: It really sounds like this is a question about basic computer skills, not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new text file, and make it end in `.rb`. You can write your ruby code in that file.